# How do I find out what company a user belongs to?

Tags: api, force.com

If I do a "get" on my own user record, I get back the following:

```
{:LastModifiedById "005i05lEwPAAU",
 :LastModifiedDate "2015-08-31T16:59:56.000+0000",
 :UserPreferencesEventRemindersCheckboxDefault true,
 :ManagerId nil,
 :Signature nil,
 :UserPreferencesHideChatterOnboardingSplash true,
 :UserPreferencesContentNoEmail false,
 :FirstName "Lawrence",
 :OfflineTrialExpirationDate nil,
 :UserPermissionsWorkDotComUserFeature false,
 :EmployeeNumber nil,
 :UserPermissionsOfflineUser false,
 :UserPreferencesShowPostalCodeToGuestUsers false,
 :UserPreferencesShowManagerToGuestUsers false,
 :FullPhotoUrl "https://c.na15.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/F",
 :UserPermissionsInteractionUser false,
 :UserPermissionsMobileUser false,
 :Fax nil,
 :UserPreferencesShowWorkPhoneToExternalUsers false,
 :UserPreferencesShowMobilePhoneToGuestUsers false,
 :UserPreferencesDisableBookmarkEmail false,
 :UserPreferencesShowProfilePicToGuestUsers false,
 :ReceivesInfoEmails false,
 :LastViewedDate "2015-09-24T20:04:56.000+0000",
 :AccountId nil,
 :UserPreferencesShowTitleToGuestUsers false,
 :SenderEmail nil,
 :Id "005i05lEwPAAU",
 :UserPreferencesShowEmailToGuestUsers false,
 :CallCenterId nil,
 :UserPreferencesDisableFileShareNotificationsForApi false,
 :EmailPreferencesAutoBcc true,
 :UserPreferencesShowStreetAddressToExternalUsers false,
 :EmailEncodingKey "ISO-8859-1",
 :UserPreferencesDisableEndorsementEmail false,
 :Email "lawrence@rollioforce.com",
 :DefaultGroupNotificationFrequency "N",
 :CreatedDate "2015-05-26T13:10:28.000+0000",
 :City nil,
 :Title nil,
 :UserPreferencesProcessAssistantCollapsed false,
 :UserPreferencesShowManagerToExternalUsers false,
 :UserPreferencesShowPostalCodeToExternalUsers false,
 :SmallPhotoUrl "https://c.na15.content.force.com/profilephoto/05/T",
 :CommunityNickname "Lawrence",
 :ProfileId "00ei00004geAAC",
 :StayInTouchNote nil,
 :UserPreferencesShowFaxToExternalUsers false,
 :UserPreferencesHideSecondChatterOnboardingSplash true,
 :ForecastEnabled false,
 :UserPreferencesHideCSNGetChatterMobileTask false,
 :UserType "Standard",
 :UserPreferencesDisableFollowersEmail false,
 :Address nil,
 :LastName "Krubner",
 :SenderName nil,
 :MobilePhone "+1 4348257694",
 :UserPreferencesReminderSoundOff false,
 :EmailPreferencesStayInTouchReminder true,
 :UserPreferencesShowCountryToExternalUsers false,
 :UserPreferencesShowStateToExternalUsers false,
 :UserPreferencesDisableLikeEmail true,
 :StayInTouchSignature nil,
 :CompanyName nil,
 :Extension nil,
 :UserPreferencesShowFaxToGuestUsers false,
 :DigestFrequency "D",
 :UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail false,
 :UserPreferencesEnableAutoSubForFeeds false,
 :UserRoleId nil,
 :SystemModstamp "2015-09-24T05:01:28.000+0000",
 :UserPreferencesShowWorkPhoneToGuestUsers false,
 :IsActive true,
 :Longitude nil,
 :LanguageLocaleKey "en_US",
 :UserPreferencesShowMobilePhoneToExternalUsers false,
 :LocaleSidKey "en_US",
 :UserPreferencesHideCSNDesktopTask false,
 :Department nil,
 :UserPreferencesDisableFeedbackEmail false,
 :Phone nil,
 :LastLoginDate "2015-09-25T04:56:29.000+0000",
 :UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser false,
 :UserPreferencesDisableSharePostEmail false,
 :FederationIdentifier nil,
 :BadgeText "",
 :UserPreferencesApexPagesDeveloperMode false,
 :UserPreferencesDisableLaterCommentEmail false,
 :CreatedById "005ZRAGA4",
 :ContactId nil,
 :Latitude nil,
 :StayInTouchSubject nil,
 :EmailPreferencesAutoBccStayInTouch false,
 :UserPermissionsCallCenterAutoLogin false,
 :UserPreferencesShowCountryToGuestUsers false,
 :UserPermissionsSiteforceContributorUser false,
 :Name "Lawrence Krubner",
 :UserPreferencesShowStateToGuestUsers false,
 :UserPreferencesHideS1BrowserUI false,
 :UserPermissionsChatterAnswersUser false,
 :ReceivesAdminInfoEmails true,
 :UserPreferencesTaskRemindersCheckboxDefault true,
 :UserPreferencesDisableWorkEmail false,
 :UserPreferencesDisProfPostCommentEmail false,
 :State nil,
 :UserPreferencesDisCommentAfterLikeEmail false,
 :UserPreferencesDisableMentionsPostEmail false,
 :AboutMe nil,
 :Country nil,
 :UserPreferencesShowCityToGuestUsers false,
 :DelegatedApproverId nil,
 :Street nil,
 :LastReferencedDate "2015-09-24T20:04:56.000+0000",
 :Alias "lkrub",
 :attributes
 {:type "User",
  :url "/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/User/005i05lEwPAAU"},
 :Username "lawrence@rollioforce.com",
 :UserPreferencesDisMentionsCommentEmail false,
 :UserPermissionsSFContentUser true,
 :UserPreferencesShowCityToExternalUsers false,
 :UserPermissionsSiteforcePublisherUser false,
 :UserPreferencesShowEmailToExternalUsers false,
 :UserPreferencesShowTitleToExternalUsers true,
 :TimeZoneSidKey "America/Panama",
 :LastPasswordChangeDate "2015-08-24T16:43:41.000+0000",
 :UserPreferencesContentEmailAsAndWhen false,
 :UserPreferencesDisableChangeCommentEmail false,
 :UserPermissionsMarketingUser false,
 :OfflinePdaTrialExpirationDate nil,
 :UserPermissionsSupportUser false,
 :PostalCode nil,
 :UserPreferencesDisableProfilePostEmail false,
 :Division nil,
 :UserPreferencesDisableMessageEmail false,
 :UserPreferencesShowStreetAddressToGuestUsers false,
 :UserPreferencesActivityRemindersPopup true}
```

I see nothing here that tells me which company I belong to.

Given a thousand users, logging in from their iPhones, I need to figure out what company they belong to. The iPhone will send a long an access token I can use to find their data, but what query do I run to find out which company they belong to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two scenarios:-

1. If users are from separate Organizations:
   You can query to Organization object in Salesforce query would be like this:

   `'SELECT Name FROM Organization'.`

   `Name` will be their company name.
2. If users are from one Organization but have may have separate Accounts:
   You can query to User's Contact's Account object in Salesforce. Query would be like this:

   `'SELECT Contact.Account.Name FROM User WHERE Username='lawrence@rollioforce.com'.`

   `Username` can be get from the response you got. `Contact.Account.Name` should be their company name.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but if I do this:  https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/query?q=SELECT+Contact.Account.Name+FROM+User+WHERE+Username%3D%27lawrence%40rollioforce.com%27

I get: 

{:totalSize 1,
 :done true,
 :records
 [{:attributes
   {:type "User",
    :url "/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/User/005i0005lEwPAAU"},
   :Contact nil}]}

Comment: So Contact is nil. And "'SELECT Name FROM Organization'." returns nothing.

Comment: There has to be someway to find out where a person works, given their user credentials? If a sales person logs in from their iPhone then we have their access_token. Surely there is some query we can run to find out their employer?

Comment: My bad, this did work: 'SELECT Name FROM Organization'.

Answer (score 0):

It does show the company name field.

```
:CompanyName nil
```

However, according to this, you do not have that populated. In order to get that from the "get" command that you ran, you will need to populate this field on the user profiles. Otherwise, you will need to do additional queries like @Ashwani shows.

If you know what this should be for everyone, you can do a mass update to the user names to update that information.

Comment: I have no way of knowing what the Company name is, nor do I have the authority to populate the fields in a user account, so I went with the queries that were show by Ashwani.